# Permissions needed to call DBMS_DATAPUMP from within package

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, datapump

I am attempting to write a procedure (within a package) that calls `DBMS_DATAPUMP` to copy an existing schema into a different schema. The code works when executed from an anonymous block, but from a procedure I get the following error.

```
[Error] Execution (1: 1): ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 1137
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 5285
ORA-06512: at "UTILITY.MANAGE_SCHEMA", line 71
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

This error is being generated from the `DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN` call. Since it works in the anonymous block, I'm assuming this is actually a permissions issue (i.e. one or more  permissions granted via a role are required). However, I can't find any documentation about what permissions are necessary to use datapump.

This problem boils down to: which permissions need to be explicitly granted to a user/schema in order for a package in that schema to be able to call `DBMS_DATAPUMP`?

---

The owner of the package has both the `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` and `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` roles, as well as the `DBA` role.

The procedure code is below.

```
   PROCEDURE copy_schema (p_source_schema VARCHAR2,
                          p_target_schema VARCHAR2,
                          p_asynchronous BOOLEAN := FALSE,
                          p_link_name VARCHAR2 := 'prddb') IS
      dph NUMBER;
      v_source_schema VARCHAR2 (30)
         := UPPER (DBMS_ASSERT.simple_sql_name (p_source_schema));
      v_target_schema VARCHAR2 (30)
         := UPPER (DBMS_ASSERT.simple_sql_name (p_target_schema));
      v_link_name VARCHAR2 (30)
         := UPPER (DBMS_ASSERT.qualified_sql_name (p_link_name));
      v_job_name VARCHAR2 (30) := UPPER ('IMPORT_' || p_target_schema);
      v_state VARCHAR2 (30);
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            'Starting copy: source_schema = '
         || v_source_schema
         || '; target_schema = '
         || v_target_schema
         || '; link_name = '
         || v_link_name
         || '; job_name = '
         || v_job_name);
      dph :=
         DBMS_DATAPUMP.open ('IMPORT',
                             'SCHEMA',
                             v_link_name,
                             v_job_name);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('dph = ' || dph);
      DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_filter (dph,
                                     'SCHEMA_LIST',
                                     '''' || v_source_schema || '''');
      DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_remap (dph,
                                    'REMAP_SCHEMA',
                                    v_source_schema,
                                    v_target_schema);
      DBMS_DATAPUMP.set_parameter (dph, 'TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION', 'REPLACE');
      DBMS_DATAPUMP.create_job_view (dph, UPPER (v_job_name || '_vw'));
      DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job (dph);

      IF NOT p_asynchronous THEN
         DBMS_DATAPUMP.wait_for_job (dph, v_state);
      END IF;
   END copy_schema;
```

---

I have found [one solution](http://allthingsoracle.com/automating-and-delegating-datapump-imports-with-plsql/) to creating a procedure that calls datapump, but it solves the problem by putting the procedure in the `SYSTEM` schema, which I would prefer not to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: `CREATE TABLE` must be explictly granted to the object owner for `DBMS_DATAPUMP` to be called from within a package or stored procedure.

---

Long Answer:

In an effort to solve this question, I interrogated the data dictionary to get all of the object and system privileges granted by the `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` and `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` roles (and all roles assigned to those two roles). Attempting to explicitly grant all 2683 privileges resulted in 2566 failures, but the package was able to call `DBMS_DATAPUMP` successfully.

The question then became: which of the remaining 117 privileges are actually needed for `DBMS_DATAPUMP`? I then grouped the remaining privileges and revoked them one group at a time (I assumed that it was a group of related permissions that would ultimately be needed). After running through nearly all of the groups, only the set of `CREATE ANY` privileges remained. When I revoked that group, the package stopped working. I then granted each of those permissions, calling the package after each grant. It was finally `CREATE ANY TABLE` that restored functionality to the package. A little further tinkering determined that `CREATE TABLE` is, in fact, sufficient to call `DBMS_DATAPUMP` from within a package.

---

`CREATE TABLE` is the only permission that I've found needs to be granted for the functionality found in the procedure shown in the question. Other procedures/datapump settings may require additional privileges. `dbms_datapump.create_job_view`, for instance, requires `CREATE VIEW`. In that case, the error message when the privilege is missing is, more reasonably, `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`.

Comment: Excellent analysis! This solution worked for me. I am using AWS Oracle RDS and ran into this issue for the rds master user. 
I logged in as master  then executed  
GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO MASTER; 

surprise! in AWS RDS I could grant privileges to myself :) . This resolved my ORA-06512: at SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP errors.

Comment: Nine years later, and this answer is still getting mileage! Right on the money.

Answer (score 0):

Privileges acquired via roles are not effective in a stored procedure. You need to grant the required privileges to the account that creates the package.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm assuming that it's a permissions issue. The gist of the question is _which_ permissions are needed to use `DBMS_DATAPUMP`?

Answer (score 0):

it's also worth noting that a lack of tablespace quota will also generate the same error :

```
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
```

although if this is the cause it happens in both anon blocks and procedures.

Comment: The downvote almost made me skip this answer. But it was exactly what I needed.